# Mixed vs Equal Characteristic Local Rings

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, intuition, p-adic-number-theory

This is more of a vague, intuitive type of question, so perhaps there isn't anything too concrete anyone can offer.

I am trying to get a sense of precisely why working with local rings of equal characteristic (char($R$) = char($R/\mathfrak{m}$)) are somehow "easier" than working with rings of mixed characteristic (char($R$) = $0$ but char$(R/\mathfrak{m}) = p$).

I can understand rings of characteristic $0$ being generally nicer than those with positive characteristic, but are there any specific results that are easy to prove in equal characteristic but remain very difficult to see/prove in mixed characteristic? I can think of theorems which are easy to prove in function fields (equal characteristic) but are hard/still not known for $p$-adic fields (mixed characteristic), but I can't think of something unifying the two equal characteristic cases and leaving out the mixed case.

Comment: Here’s a simple-minded contribution: equal-characteristic rings are power-series rings, you can “see” exactly what’s going on; mixed-characterstic rings are not power-series rings.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for your comment. That makes sense that equal characteristic should feel like power-series, whereas mixed characteristic rings do not feel like that at all. I suppose that makes sense because in equal characteristic, R is an R/m vector space, i.e. a free module over a ring with the same characteristic.

Comment: Yes, just so. But don’t get the idea that the basis consists of nothing but the monomials!

Comment: In power / Laurent series you have no "carries", that makes the absic arithmetic easier. Compute $(3+7x)(5+2x+8x^2)$ in $\mathbb Z[[x]]$, hence in $\mathbb Q[[x]]$ and $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$, versus $(3+7p)(5+2p+8p^2)$ in $\mathbb Z_p$ for $p=2,3,5,7,17$ to get a feeling.